# Adding class to body based on seasons/time

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm using Wordpress (which may or may not be relevant) but I'm trying to add a class to the body based on the time of the year.

I have three 'themes' on the site; spring, summer and autumn. If the period is Feb-May, for example, the class on the body would be 'spring'. If the period is Jun-September the class on the body would be 'summer', and so forth.

Any ideas how I would achieve this?

Currently the body already has relevant classes based on which page you are on (Wordpress default) which looks like this

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

But you can add your own class by doing

```
<body <?php body_class('a-new-class'); ?>>
```

Any help would be appreciated — I'm guessing a simple PHP if statement to do with dates?

Cheers,
R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP:

```
function getSeasonCssClass() {
  $month = date('n'); // current month number without leading 0
  $season = array(
    1 => 'winter',
    2 => 'winter',
    3 => 'winter',
    4 => 'spring',
    5 => 'spring',
    6 => 'spring',
    7 => 'summer',
    8 => 'summer',
    9 => 'summer',
    10 => 'autumn',
    11 => 'autumn',
    12 => 'autumn',
  );
  return $season[$month];
}
```

HTML:

```
<body <?php body_class(getSeasonCssClass());?>>
```

Comment: Great enough for me — this makes perfect sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The seasons are reversed in the southern hemisphere. For example, this would be completely wrong for somebody in Australia.